# .htaccess redirect subdirectory to subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the URL `http://example.com/sub-folder/filename.html` to `http://example.com/sub-folder/index.php?p=filename.html`

I already have the following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^stedentrip-naar/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$  stedentrip-naar/index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^stedentrip-naar/(.*)$ /stedentrip-naar/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: So what's wrong? What's the question?

Comment: I get an 404 not found on the page

Comment: Check out your apache error logs. They will have more information about the request that might point you in a better direction. Also, I could be wrong, but it appears you are redirecting anything that falls under a directory to that same directory. Does the `/stedentrip-naar/` directory even exist?

Comment: No, my .htaccess file exists in the root of the public_html. The /stedentrip-naar/ does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your `/sub-folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /stedentrip-naar/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+\.html)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I'm keep getting a white screen now, is it the [L,QSA,NC] at the end of the line that causes this?

Comment: THat should not be causing it. You can open your page in Firebug and see if there is any 404 for image/css/js files?

Comment: Strange, no errors at all, I get a 200 page ok in my network tab and my php error reporting is on.

Comment: And if you open `/stedentrip-naar/index.php?p=filename.html` does it work?

Comment: Its not working either, so the htaccess is fine. I will search for a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: If you encounter a different problem, feel free to create a new question to get speedy help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^sub-folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ sub-folder/index.php?p=$1.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think something like this is the solution but this doesnt work. I still got the 404 error. I tried it like this.

RewriteRule ^stedentrip-naar/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ stedentrip-naar/index.php?p=$1